# EF Core: Only base class properties are shown when querying with .ToList()

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

I've been having a problem for a while now and after a lot of searching on StackOverflow/Google I'm still not been able to fix my problem. I'm using .NET Core with the latest version of EF Core. I'm writing an API for my school project.

I created the following DbSets in my `DbContext`:

```
        public DbSet<Base> Bases { get; set; }
        
        public DbSet<A> As { get; set; }

        public DbSet<B> Bs { get; set; }
        
        public abstract class Base
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            
            public string Type { get; set; }
        }

        public class A : Base
        {
            public string AString { get; set; }
        }

        public class B : Base
        {
            public string BString { get; set; }
        }
```

I seeded the DbSets with the following data:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<A>()
                .HasData(new A
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    Type = "A",
                    AString = "A Entity"
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity<B>()
                .HasData(new B
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    Type = "B",
                    BString = "B Entity"
                });
```

When I query with `_context.Bases.ToList() OR _context.Bases.ToListAsync()` I get the following result:

```
[
 {
   "id" = 1,
   "type" = "A"
   // Here I would expect the AString property as well, but it's not there
 }
,
{
   "id" = 2,
   "type" = "B",
   // And here I would expect the BString property as well
}
]
```

I would expect the AString and BString property to be shown as well but I can't manage to fix it. Im using NPGSQL and my table looks like this:

```
studentenkuis=# SELECT * FROM "Bases";
 Id | Type | Discriminator | AString  | BString
----+------+---------------+----------+----------
  1 | A    | A             | A Entity |
  2 | B    | B             |          | B Entity
```

**EDIT**
Im using the following API Call to return the queried data:

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> allBases()
        {
            return Ok(await _context.Bases.ToListAsync());
        }
```

Ive tried the following as well:

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> allBases()
        {
            var bases = await _context.Bases.ToListAsync();
            return Ok(bases);
        }
```

Comment: You are confusing whatever you are using to convert to JSON (as per your "result"), which might use the actual variable type (and not the object type) to convert it, to "what's inside your object"

Comment: @Jcl Thanks for replying, I've added the API call in which I return the queried data.

Comment: You should not have a `DbSet` of an abstract class... only have the two concrete classes and query them.

Comment: @crgolden In my use case I'm getting a lot of different types, like 8 or 10 different types. If i understand you correctly, I have to query ALL of the types seperately?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise, how would EF know which derived class you're talking about?

Comment: `after a lot of searching on StackOverflow/Google I'm still not been able to fix my problem` you're probably searching for the wrong thing. You're using inheritance with [table-per-hierarchy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-hierarchy-and-discriminator-configuration) and trying to return all derived classes.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance

Comment: @crgolden I thought, by looking at the Postgres table, I would be able to return that table (So IF a derived property is present add it to the result).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for replying! I've looked into TPH and that kind of stuff several times, I'm still not able to fix it properly

Comment: @florissmit1 LINQ isn't SQL. It produces *mapped objects*. What type of objects would a query on the base class produce? The only thing you told the compiler is that the results should contain the *base properties*. [PostgreSQL supports inheritance too](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/tutorial-inheritance.html) but you can't retrieve derived table fields through the parent table

Comment: If what you want is the table that postgres produces, then you need yo have a type that includes properties for **all** the columns in that table so they can be mapped, and neither `Bases`, nor `A`, nor `B` has all of them in your sample.